# Handling dervied types in a function accepting base type

Tags: c#

First I apologize if this has already been asked. I am having a difficult time putting my problem into words. So as shown in code snippet below, I have an interface `ISomeInterface` which has a function `CalculateSomething` which takes as a parameter `ICalculationInput`. I have multiple types implementing `ISomeInterface`, and each implementation requires slightly different parameters to `CalculateSomething`. Hence `CalculateSomething` accepts `ICalculationInput` instead of specific parameters. Now in each implementation of function `CalculateSomething` I am forced to cast it to the specific type before using it which is making the code a bit ugly. I would like to hear your input on how to redesign this so I don't have to cast the parameters, so I can avoid run-time errors and don't get embarrassed when i read my code again after a few years.

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    void CalculateSomething(ICalculationInput input);
}

class SpecificClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public void CalculateSomething(ICalculationInput input)
    {
        var spInput = ICalculationInput as SpecificInput;
        if(spInput == null) throw ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `SpecificInput` always? Then change the interface to `CalculateSomething(SpecificInput input)`

Comment: If you are not embarrassed by the code you wrote a few years back, you are not learning enough...;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have different implementations of ISomeInterface and each implementation has its own input parameter type deriving from ICalculationInput

Comment: You're going to need generics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SpecificClass` by design cannot ever hope to make `CalculateSomething` work for anything other than `SpecificInput`, it should generally have a `CalculateSomething(SpecificInput)` method, not a `CalculateSomething(ICalculationInput)` method. Sometimes practical concerns get in the way, but not so here. If `ISomeInterface` is only implemented by that one class, then it's easy: just change the interface. Otherwise, if some classes need some specific input class, and other classes need a different specific input class, parameterise:

```
interface ISomeInterface<T>
{
    void CalculateSomething(T input);
}

class SpecificClass : ISomeInterface<SpecificInput>
{
    public void CalculateSomething(SpecificInput input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Optionally, if it makes sense, you can add a `where T : ICalculationInput` constraint to your interface.

If for whatever reason you cannot change the interface, you can still use a base class to provide a single common implementation for the methods, which would look something like:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    void CalculateSomething(ICalculationInput input);
}

abstract class SomeInterfaceBase<T> : ISomeInterface
{
    public abstract void CalculateSomething(T input);

    void ISomeInterface.CalculateSomething(ICalculationInput input)
    {
        var concreteInput = input as T;
        if (concreteInput == null)
        {
            if (input == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("input must be a T", "input");
        }
        CalculateSomething(concreteInput);
    }
}

class SpecificClass : SomeInterfaceBase<SpecificInput>
{
    public override void CalculateSomething(SpecificInput input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

<sub>I suspect there are minor errors in the above, but the concept should nevertheless be workable.</sub>

Comment: I ended up using a solution close to what you have suggested. Thanks!